# A generalisation of residual finiteness?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, free-groups

A group $\Gamma$ is Residually Finite (RF) if
$\forall g \neq e \in \Gamma$ there is a homomorphism $h: \Gamma \to G$ where $G$ is a finite group such that $h(g) \neq e$. Free groups are known to be RF.

I would like to swap the quantifiers in the definition of RF above for the case of free groups over $n$ generators: Let us call the free group $F_n = \langle S \cup S^{-1}\rangle$ over the generating set $S = \{g_1, \dots, g_n\}$ $\ell$-Strong Residually Finite ($\ell$-SRF) if $\exists h: F_n \to G$ where $G$ is a finite group, such that for every $g \neq e$ $|g| \leq \ell$ (where now we consider $g$ as word of length $\ell$ over $S \cup S^{-1}$) $h(g) \neq e$.

Are there examples of $\ell$-SRF groups for some $\ell = \ell(n)$? Has this notion that has been studied before somewhere? If yes, is it possible to bound the size of the finite group as a function of $n$?

Comment: But surely all free groups of finite rank satisfy this condition, because they are RF and there are only finitely many elements of length at most $\ell$? I have no idea about the bound on the order of the finite group.

Comment: Khalid Bou-rabee and others have studied bounds on this starting with this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0862

Comment: This is not exactly about quantitative residual finiteness in the usual sense (which is about bounding the index of a subgroup not containing *one* element of length $\ell$). Actually this question is about girth of Cayley graphs. The question is exactly asking how large $G$ must be if it has a Cayley graph on $n$ generators with girth at least $\ell+1$. Random Cayley graphs of $\mathrm{SL}_2(p)$ have girth $c \log p$.

Comment: Although the phrasing of the question in the last paragraph is odd and doesn't seem to reflect the intention of the previous paragraphs. $F_n$ Is "$\ell$-SRF" for all $\ell$, so $\ell(n) = \infty$ I guess. It makes more sense to ask for a bound for $|G|$ in terms of $\ell$ and $n$.

Comment: If $X$ is a class of groups (say closed under taking subgroups), a group $G$ is said to be "fully residually finite" if for every finite subset $F$ of $G$ there is a homomorphism from $G$ to a group in $X$ that is injective on $F$. If $X$ is closed under finite direct products, then this is the same as "residually X".

Comment: The quantified version you mentioned: $n\mapsto c(n)$ smallest quotient on which the $n$-ball is mapped injectively is (more or less) called normal systolic growth.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks! yes - indeed I'm looking for a bound for $|G|$ in terms of $n$ (since I am looking at the case where $\ell$ as a function of $n$ too). Is there any known upper/lower bounds? For eg. could it be that there exist groups where $|G|$ is polynomially bounded in $n$? Note that $n$ is the number of generators of the free group here.

Comment: It is easy to see that $|G| \ge |B(\ell/2)| \ge (2n-1)^{\ell/2}$ (this is essentially the Moore bound from graph theory).